# undefined references ATLAS, MPI, CBLAS when compiling HPL in Centos6

Tags: mpi, atlas

I am trying to run HPL 2.1 in my Centos systems.

This is my make file:

```
[root@cadejos-0 hpl]# cat Make.cadejos 
#  
#  -- High Performance Computing Linpack Benchmark (HPL)                
#     HPL - 2.1 - October 26, 2012                          
#     Antoine P. Petitet                                                
#     University of Tennessee, Knoxville                                
#     Innovative Computing Laboratory                                 
#     (C) Copyright 2000-2008 All Rights Reserved                       
#                                                                       
#  -- Copyright notice and Licensing terms:                             
#                                                                       
#  Redistribution  and  use in  source and binary forms, with or without
#  modification, are  permitted provided  that the following  conditions
#  are met:                                                             
#                                                                       
#  1. Redistributions  of  source  code  must retain the above copyright
#  notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.        
#                                                                       
#  2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce  the above copyright
#  notice, this list of conditions,  and the following disclaimer in the
#  documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution. 
#                                                                       
#  3. All  advertising  materials  mentioning  features  or  use of this
#  software must display the following acknowledgement:                 
#  This  product  includes  software  developed  at  the  University  of
#  Tennessee, Knoxville, Innovative Computing Laboratory.             
#                                                                       
#  4. The name of the  University,  the name of the  Laboratory,  or the
#  names  of  its  contributors  may  not  be used to endorse or promote
#  products  derived   from   this  software  without  specific  written
#  permission.                                                          
#                                                                       
#  -- Disclaimer:                                                       
#                                                                       
#  THIS  SOFTWARE  IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
#  ``AS IS'' AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES,  INCLUDING,  BUT NOT
#  LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR
#  A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE UNIVERSITY
#  OR  CONTRIBUTORS  BE  LIABLE FOR ANY  DIRECT,  INDIRECT,  INCIDENTAL,
#  SPECIAL,  EXEMPLARY,  OR  CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES  (INCLUDING,  BUT NOT
#  LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE,
#  DATA OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION)  HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY
#  THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT,  STRICT LIABILITY,  OR TORT
#  (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
#  OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE. 
# ######################################################################
#  
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# - shell --------------------------------------------------------------
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#
SHELL        = /bin/sh
#
CD           = cd
CP           = cp
LN_S         = ln -s
MKDIR        = mkdir
RM           = /bin/rm -f
TOUCH        = touch
#
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# - Platform identifier ------------------------------------------------
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#
ARCH         = Linux_PII_CBLAS
#
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# - HPL Directory Structure / HPL library ------------------------------
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#
TOPdir       = $(HOME)/hpl
INCdir       = $(TOPdir)/include
BINdir       = $(TOPdir)/bin/$(ARCH)
LIBdir       = $(TOPdir)/lib/$(ARCH)
#
HPLlib       = $(LIBdir)/libhpl.a 
#
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# - Message Passing library (MPI) --------------------------------------
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# MPinc tells the  C  compiler where to find the Message Passing library
# header files,  MPlib  is defined  to be the name of  the library to be
# used. The variable MPdir is only used for defining MPinc and MPlib.
#
MPdir        = /usr/include/mpich2-x86_64
MPinc        = -I$(MPdir)
MPlib        = /usr/lib64/mpich2/lib/libmpich.a

#
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# - Linear Algebra library (BLAS or VSIPL) -----------------------------
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# LAinc tells the  C  compiler where to find the Linear Algebra  library
# header files,  LAlib  is defined  to be the name of  the library to be
# used. The variable LAdir is only used for defining LAinc and LAlib.
#
LAdir        = /usr/include/atlas-x86_64-base/
LAinc        = -I$(LAdir)
LAlib        = /usr/lib64/atlas/libatlas.a /usr/lib64/atlas/libcblas.a
#
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# - F77 / C interface --------------------------------------------------
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# You can skip this section  if and only if  you are not planning to use
# a  BLAS  library featuring a Fortran 77 interface.  Otherwise,  it  is
# necessary  to  fill out the  F2CDEFS  variable  with  the  appropriate
# options.  **One and only one**  option should be chosen in **each** of
# the 3 following categories:
#
# 1) name space (How C calls a Fortran 77 routine)
#
# -DAdd_              : all lower case and a suffixed underscore  (Suns,
#                       Intel, ...),                           [default]
# -DNoChange          : all lower case (IBM RS6000),
# -DUpCase            : all upper case (Cray),
# -DAdd__             : the FORTRAN compiler in use is f2c.
#
# 2) C and Fortran 77 integer mapping
#
# -DF77_INTEGER=int   : Fortran 77 INTEGER is a C int,         [default]
# -DF77_INTEGER=long  : Fortran 77 INTEGER is a C long,
# -DF77_INTEGER=short : Fortran 77 INTEGER is a C short.
#
# 3) Fortran 77 string handling
#
# -DStringSunStyle    : The string address is passed at the string loca-
#                       tion on the stack, and the string length is then
#                       passed as  an  F77_INTEGER  after  all  explicit
#                       stack arguments,                       [default]
# -DStringStructPtr   : The address  of  a  structure  is  passed  by  a
#                       Fortran 77  string,  and the structure is of the
#                       form: struct {char *cp; F77_INTEGER len;},
# -DStringStructVal   : A structure is passed by value for each  Fortran
#                       77 string,  and  the  structure is  of the form:
#                       struct {char *cp; F77_INTEGER len;},
# -DStringCrayStyle   : Special option for  Cray  machines,  which  uses
#                       Cray  fcd  (fortran  character  descriptor)  for
#                       interoperation.
#
F2CDEFS      =
#
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# - HPL includes / libraries / specifics -------------------------------
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#
HPL_INCLUDES = -I$(INCdir) -I$(INCdir)/$(ARCH) $(LAinc) $(MPinc)
HPL_LIBS     = $(HPLlib) $(LAlib) $(MPlib)
#
# - Compile time options -----------------------------------------------
#
# -DHPL_COPY_L           force the copy of the panel L before bcast;
# -DHPL_CALL_CBLAS       call the cblas interface;
# -DHPL_CALL_VSIPL       call the vsip  library;
# -DHPL_DETAILED_TIMING  enable detailed timers;
#
# By default HPL will:
#    *) not copy L before broadcast,
#    *) call the BLAS Fortran 77 interface,
#    *) not display detailed timing information.
#
HPL_OPTS     = -DHPL_CALL_CBLAS -DHPL_DETAILED_TIMING
#
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#
HPL_DEFS     = $(F2CDEFS) $(HPL_OPTS) $(HPL_INCLUDES)
#
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# - Compilers / linkers - Optimization flags ---------------------------
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#
CC           = /usr/bin/gcc
CCNOOPT      = $(HPL_DEFS)
CCFLAGS      = $(HPL_DEFS) -fomit-frame-pointer -O3 -funroll-loops
#
# On some platforms,  it is necessary  to use the Fortran linker to find
# the Fortran internals used in the BLAS library.
#
LINKER       = /usr/bin/g77
LINKFLAGS    = $(CCFLAGS)
#
ARCHIVER     = ar
ARFLAGS      = r
RANLIB       = echo
#
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I got some errors fixed here and there but i cant get past this lot o' undefined references:

```
/usr/bin/gcc -o HPL_pdtest.o -c  -DHPL_CALL_CBLAS -DHPL_DETAILED_TIMING -I/root/hpl/include -I/root/hpl/include/Linux_PII_CBLAS -I/usr/include/atlas-x86_64-base/ -I/usr/include/mpich2-x86_64 -fomit-frame-pointer -O3 -funroll-loops  ../HPL_pdtest.c
/usr/bin/g77  -DHPL_CALL_CBLAS -DHPL_DETAILED_TIMING -I/root/hpl/include -I/root/hpl/include/Linux_PII_CBLAS -I/usr/include/atlas-x86_64-base/ -I/usr/include/mpich2-x86_64 -fomit-frame-pointer -O3 -funroll-loops -o /root/hpl/bin/Linux_PII_CBLAS/xhpl HPL_pddriver.o         HPL_pdinfo.o           HPL_pdtest.o /root/hpl/lib/Linux_PII_CBLAS/libhpl.a  /usr/lib64/atlas/libatlas.a /usr/lib64/atlas/libcblas.a /usr/lib64/mpich2/lib/libmpich.a
/usr/lib64/atlas/libcblas.a(cblas_dgemm.o): In function `cblas_dgemm':
(.text+0x321): undefined reference to `ATL_dsyrk'
/usr/lib64/atlas/libcblas.a(cblas_dgemm.o): In function `cblas_dgemm':
(.text+0x186): undefined reference to `ATL_dgemm'
/usr/lib64/atlas/libcblas.a(cblas_dgemm.o): In function `cblas_dgemm':
(.text+0x35e): undefined reference to `ATL_dsyreflect'
... A LOT MORE ...
/usr/lib64/mpich2/lib/libmpich.a(info_getvallen.o): In function `MPI_Info_get_valuelen':
(.text+0x37b): undefined reference to `pthread_setspecific'
/usr/lib64/mpich2/lib/libmpich.a(info_getvallen.o): In function `MPI_Info_get_valuelen':
(.text+0x38d): undefined reference to `pthread_getspecific'
/usr/lib64/mpich2/lib/libmpich.a(info_getvallen.o): In function `MPI_Info_get_valuelen':
(.text+0x3b7): undefined reference to `pthread_setspecific'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [dexe.grd] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/hpl/testing/ptest/cadejos'
make[1]: *** [build_tst] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/hpl'
make: *** [build] Error 2
```

I think it has something to do with the libs path but i am unable to go on...

Has anyone run into this kind or problem?

Answer (score 0):

looks like its not finding atlas and pthreads

`undefined reference to 'ATL_dsyreflect'`

`undefined reference to 'pthread_setspecific'`

you will need to link to this properly or in the case of atlas it could be built incorrectly.

i believe pthreads requires a `-lpthread` flag  which i do no see above and I also do not see anything with atlas

Answer (score 0):

As for the Pthreads error: every MPI library requires a certain number of external dependencies to be linked when building the final executable. That's why it is not a good idea to use `gcc` or `g77` to link an MPI executable. Rather `mpicc` or `mpif90` or another MPI compiler wrapper should be used. Anyways, Pthreads is linked if `-pthread` is specified.

As for the ATLAS errors: the order in which **static** libraries are listed on the command line matters (it doesn't for dynamic libraries). In your case you have:

```
... /usr/lib64/atlas/libatlas.a /usr/lib64/atlas/libcblas.a ...
```

With such an arrangement the linker won't be able to resolve any references from code inside `libcblas.a` to code inside `libatlas.a`. This is due to the single pass symbol resolution done by the linker. `libcblas.a` should come before `libatlas.a`, not after.